# Android AR library to recognize objects and apply some changes

Tags: android, augmented-reality, vuforia, artoolkit, wikitude

I'm new to AR, creating an AR app to **"try wall painting"**. User start the app, scan's the wall and choose color to paint the wall virtually. 
Which library is good for this kind of app.

Does **ARToolkit** provides object recognition so that I can detect the wall and objects on the wall.

**Wikitude** has **cloud recognition API** but I'm not sure this can be done with it.

**VuForia** is one more library but I haven't tried.

Comment: Are you aware of Tango (old name Project Tango) which is closer to the AR you are thinking of: https://get.google.com/tango/ Its requires special cameras on the device. Existing phones/tablets would have a floating wall of color for your idea, less so with Tango.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't get the last part, so apps created using Tango supports existing phone/tablets or not?

Comment: Ok so it doesn't support existing devices. Lenovo has on device which supports Tango. But my users have normal devices/tablets so what is the solution for those?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, for using Vuforia or ARToolkit kind of libraries, you need to have enough features for them to detect. These libraries search for images which you load into their database in advance. Something like a blank wall will not get detected, since it is smooth (It does not have any features). If there are objects or patterns on the wall, it might work - it depends if they have enough features for getting detected. There are indeed some good hardware-based solutions, like suggested above, but this is not what you want.
If it's not a blank wall - I suggest you take a look at Vuforia, they have some pretty good samples and articles.